# How to load images anync for TimelineQueueNavigator of ExoPlayer?

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

I am using MediaSessionConnector to manage media session. I have playlist that need to played. To control playlist and show metadata on bluetooth devices i used TimelineQueueNavigator. It also suppose to show metadata on lock screen of the device.

```
val navigator = object: TimelineQueueNavigator(mediaSession) {

       override fun getMediaDescription(player: Player?, windowIndex: Int): MediaDescriptionCompat {
         val song = mPlaylist[windowIndex]
         val bitmap = // get bitmap from somwhere
         return MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
            .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_MEDIA_ID, song.id)
            .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, song.artist)
            .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, song.name)
            .putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ART, bitmap)
            .putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_ICON, bitmap)
            .build()
       }
  }

mediaSessionConnector.setQueueNavigator(navigator)
```

This approach is good but require to have image already loaded so you can assign bitmap.

Does anyone know how to manage getMediaDescription where image is loaded async? Example will much appreciated. Or maybe it require different approach?

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked as a GitHub issue on the project repository, see [this link](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/5494#issuecomment-462476576) for the full conversation.

To sum it up, this is how you can do it:

1. In `getMediaDescription`, provide the info you already have. If you don't have the images, start fetching them asynchronically.
2. When you have all the images, call `mediaSessionConnector.invalidateMediaSessionQueue()` and `mediaSessionConnector.invalidateMediaSessionMetadata()`. This will re-call `getMediaDescription`, where you should provide the images you now have.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for the response, it was overkill for me to load all images. I was need image only for current playing song to have it on lock screen. I, eventually, implemented MediaMetadataProvider that request metadata for current song and there i was loading image and set it directly on media session via mediaSession.setMetadata().

Comment: Yes that works as well. The TimeLineQueueNavigator solution is better in the sense that you can provide images for items in the queue which are not the current one. So if the user switches to the next / previous track, the image is displayed immediately. The problem with this is that you need the bitmap ready to be provided, but mostly we use URLs in the apps, so looking up the bitmaps and updating the queue is a very difficult problem to be implemented efficiently and correctly.